# Why does using an engine in your chess games help?

Tags: engines

When I play against a max level chess engine, I can't win. However, when I calculate all the moves with a chess engine, I win every time. If chess computers are all around the same level, how was I able to checkmate the Komodo Engine with Stockfish 15? The game is [here.](https://www.chess.com/game/computer/17462143)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't know about the downvotes, but I've read the question several times and I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question either, but you have a false premise in stating that chess computers are all around the same level.

Comment: @Herb Why can a bot beat another bot?

Comment: When both of them never make mistakes?

Comment: Because one engine is stronger than the other. Saying they never make mistakes is just not true.

Answer (score 2):

> If chess computers are all around the same level

They aren't.

> how was I able to checkmate the Komodo Engine with Stockfish 15?

Using an engine is a bit like playing with "take-backs". You are never going to blunder. Somebody who knows nothing about chess but can follow an engine and copy one engine's best move to another game with another engine is still going to "play" better than Magnus Carlsen. That reflects nothing about them and everything about the choice of engines.

Comment: But if both bots never make mistakes, how was there a checkmate and not simply a draw?

Comment: You keep saying engines don't make mistakes, which just isn't true. Maybe you mean that engines don't make blunders, which I guess almost everybody would agree to.

Comment: They totally make blunders, just a 3500 elo blunder is very different from a 1500 elo blunder.

Comment: It's not right to call them blunders. At 3500 level they're tiny positional inaccuracies that are exploited over the long term.